# How can set up notifications with supabase and flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal, supabase

I am developping an chat app with flutter and supabase. I've already developped the chat functionnality and it works well.

What I want know, is to send notifications specificly to the recipient of the message.
I need help.

I tried to use supabase edge-functions and webhooks with FCM and OneSignal to set up notifications. The problem is, The app is sending notifications to all users when message is added in the messages table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.